# How to generate an extent report for POM QA automation framework with updated classes?

Tags: c#, selenium, extentreports

I am developing a QA automation framework using a Page Object Model in C#. I want to get a report about passed and failed test cases. I think [Extent Reports](https://www.extentreports.com/) is most suitable for this and I tried to run it, but extent report classes are not working. How can I integrate Extent Reports into my POM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a dependency in your POM.XML

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
  <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Use the code below to setup reporting:

```
ExtentHtmlReporter report=new ExtentHtmlReporter(path);
extentReport=new ExtentReports();
extentReport.attachReporter(report);
```

Comment: After that in your base class, add methods to setup and tear down extent report

Comment: ExtentHtmlReporter report=new ExtentHtmlReporter(path);
  
  extentReport=new ExtentReports();
  
  extentReport.attachReporter(report);

Comment: i did those things how connect with test cases

Comment: In your test case, add below code:                                                                             logger=BaseClass.extentReport.createTest("Test Case Name to be written here" , "Test Case Description to be written here");

Comment: In C# is this correct  ExtentLoggerReporter loggerReporter = extentReport.CreateTest();